# Webpack fails to compile Apollo and GraphQL modules correctly

Tags: webpack, apollo, graphql-js

I'm working on a `create-react-app` client-side application that uses Apollo and GraphQL. Currently I'm getting two types of errors when I try to `npm start`.

Error Type 1 (9x for 9 different [ **module** ]):

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 27:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './[ **module** ]' in '/Users/benosuriano/Documents/me/coding/web_dev/playground/tinyhouse_v1/client/node_modules/graphql'
Did you mean 'graphql.mjs'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './graphql' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

Error Type 2 (18x for 18 different [ **module** ]'s):

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql-tag/lib/index.js 62:17-22
export '**module**' (imported as '**module**') was not found in 'graphql' (module has no exports)
```

After doing research online, I was able to take care of of the error type 1. Inside `webpack.config.js`, under `module`, I added:
`module: { rules: resolve: { fullySpecified: false } }`.

For error type 2, I went into my `node_modules`, and checked whether or not each module was effectively being exported from `graphql`. I saw that inside `/node_modules/graphql`, there was an `index.js` and an `index.mjs`, and all exports are coming out of `index.mjs`.

According to some posts, inside `webpack.config.js`, under `resolve`, in the `extensions`, I should have `.mjs` preceed any other extensions, so that Webpack would look at `index.mjs` before `index.js`. I changed the order of extensions, but I'm still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

For error Type 1, the solution that worked for me was to add this

```
{
    test: /\.m?js/,
    resolve: {
        fullySpecified: false
    }
}
```

into the `rules` array that is under `module` section in `webpack.config`.

There are two ways how to go about it, **depending if you want to eject your app**.

#### 1. I am willing to eject:

Then its simply finding the correct place in the webpack config and adding the snippet above to the array.

#### 2. I do not want to eject:

Here, I used a library that would override the webpack configuration for me. There are few options, [see here for some suggestions](https://marmelab.com/blog/2021/07/22/cra-webpack-no-eject.html). I went with CRACO and after setting it up as suggested by their [documentation](https://craco.js.org/docs/getting-started/), this is my `craco.config.ts`:

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        configure: {
            module: {
                rules: [{
                    test: /\.m?js/,
                    resolve: {
                        fullySpecified: false
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Found this solution [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/2721#issuecomment-723008284).
Still looking into Type 2 error.